# 日本語に違和感: コメント中に出る「N 文字残っています」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

[image: 585 文字残っています]

解釈によっては「あと585文字書かなくてはいけない」と取れます。

Answer (score 1):

> 残り 585 文字

という書き方をよく見るように思います。

解釈によっては「あと585文字書かなくてはいけない」と取れる、というのはこちらも変わらないように思いますが...。

Comment: 適用しました。次回のビルドに更新します。